# What is thnuclnt, vmware

Tags: macos, process, vmware-fusion

After starting VMware, I noticed that there are more than 10 processes called 'thnuclnt'.
They're listening on the port 4000. (Since i use this port for something else, it's annoying.)

I'm wondering what this is, since I didn’t find anything about it.

I use Mac 10.5.8 with VMware Fusion 2.0.2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That process is used for VMware's virtual printing feature. They sit around waiting for data from virtual machines. (You can quit them with Activity Monitor if they're in the way, with no ill effects.)

Answer (score 7):

If you have any VMware Fusion guests running, open up the Settings -> Printers and disable this feature.  This usually will stop the thnuclnt service.

Answer (score 1):

A [VMware Communities post](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/166982) gives a conclusion that it's part of VMware Fusion:

> VMware Communities: XP SP3 VM hangs/shuts down, hangs Fusion
>
> 8 posts - 3 authors - Last post: 9 Sep 2008
>
> ... **Support/VMware Fusion/thnuclnt**/thnuclnt -pdir
>   /var/folders/i5/i5P1vGYhFAWhTofyodWXTk+++TI/-Tmp-//vmware-rg/thnuclnt-1520 -fg
>
> communities.vmware.com/thread/166982

Comment: links to google searches are not helpful, and not necessary.  just include the relevant link directly to the source you quote, please.

Comment: I will from now on then, but your comment has given me an initial impression that my answer is simply a Google search link and therefore not helpful at all. I do hope you weren't intending to convey that.

Comment: no no. *thank you* for *not* simply posting a google link.  if you (or others) examine the revision history, you can see i only removed the google link and inserted the actual source link.  (posts that consist only of a google link tend to get downvoted into oblivion, and LMGTFY links are outright banned.)